# Gridlayout Under vertical list in Recycler view

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

How to display Recyclerview grid in a recyclerview vertical list.

I need a lay that contains a vertical list. In vertical list row  i want to display a grid. This is below structure what i actually want

```
1st row Heading
 Image  image  image
 Image  Image  Image
2nd row Heading
 Image  image  image
 Image  Image  Image
3rd row Heading
 Image  image  image
 Image  Image  Image
```

How it possbile. If possible please give me link like above in example

Comment: Yes it's possible. For link you will have to google.

Comment: thanks for reply.. but i can find it on google. Can u suggest me such time of link

Comment: Check out the link suggested in the answer by @jagoan-neon

Comment: you can check https://github.com/TonicArtos/StickyGridHeaders

Answer (score 0):

Check this out. https://gist.github.com/gabrielemariotti/4c189fb1124df4556058

Or you can make use of SpanSizeLookup.

Comment: From [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/answer-bans): "Provide context for links. Link-only answers are not good answers."